# array_walk an anonymous function

Tags: php

Is there a way I can get this array walk with my anonymous function to set the values?

```
$url = array('dog', 'cat', 'fish');

array_walk($url, function(&$value, &$key) {
    $url[$key] = str_replace('dog', '', $value);
});

echo '<pre>';
print_r($url);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You are already [passing the value by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), so just do the following:

```
array_walk($url, function(&$value, &$key) {
    $value = str_replace('dog', '', $value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks man! Thats exactly it :) Ill green check this in 7 mins!

Comment: Keep in mind that with `array_walk` you cannot pass `$key` by reference. Only `$value` can be modified by reference. PHP won't throw an error if you attempt to modify the `$key`, but it won't effect the array in anyway.